# Does functional programming increase the 'representational gap' between problems and solutions?

Tags: object-oriented, object-oriented-design, functional-programming, abstraction

Since machine language (e.g., `0110101000110101`) computer languages have generally evolved to higher forms of abstraction, generally making it easier to understand the code when it's applied to a problem. Assembler was an abstraction over machine code, C was an abstraction over assembler, etc.

Object-oriented design seems to be very good at allowing us to model a problem in terms of objects, e.g., the problem of a university course registration system can be modeled with a `Course` class, a `Student` class, etc. Then, when we write the solution in an OO language, we have similar classes which get responsibilities and that generally is helpful for design, especially for modularizing the code. If I give this problem to 10 independent teams who solve it with an OO method, generally the 10 solutions will have the classes relating to the problem in common. There can be lots of differences when you start to get into coupling and interactions of those classes, so there's no such thing as "zero representational gap."

My experience with Functional Programming is very limited (no real-world use, only Hello World type programs). I'm failing to see how such languages allow easily mapping FP solutions to problems (with a low representational gap) the way OO languages do.

I understand the advantages of FP with respect to concurrent programming. But am I missing something, or is FP not about reducing a representational gap (making solutions easier to understand)?

Another way to ask this: would the FP code of 10 different teams solving the same real-world problem have a lot in common?

---

From Wikipedia on [Abstraction (computer science)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstraction_%28computer_science%29) (emphasis mine):

> Functional programming languages commonly exhibit **abstractions related to functions**, such as **lambda abstractions** (making a term into a function of some variable), **higher-order functions** (parameters are functions), **bracket abstraction** (making a term into a function of a variable).

The representational gap could be potentially increased, because [some] real-world problems aren't modeled easily with such abstractions.

---

Another way I see decreasing representational gap is in tracing the solution elements back to the problem. The `0`'s and `1`s in machine code is very hard to trace back, whereas the `Student` class is easy to trace back. Not all OO classes trace easily to the problem space, but many do.

<del>Don't FP abstractions always need explaining to find out which part of the problem space they are solving (apart from *math* problems)?</del> OK - I'm good on this part. After looking at many more examples, I see how FP abstractions are very clear for parts of the problem that are expressed in data processing.

---

The accepted answer to a related question [Can UML be used to model a Functional program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457903/can-uml-be-used-to-model-a-functional-program) -- says "Functional programmers don't have a lot of use for diagrams." I really don't care if it's UML, but it makes me wonder about FP abstractions being easy to understand/communicate, if there are no diagrams that are widely used (assuming this answer is correct). Again, my level of FP use/understanding is trivial, so I understand no need for diagrams on simple FP programs.

OO design has function/class/package-levels of abstraction, with encapsulation (access control, information hiding) at each, which makes managing complexity easier. These are elements that allow going from the problem to the solution and back easier.

---

Many answers speak of how analysis and design are done in FP in a way analogous to OO, but nobody cites anything high-level so far (paul cited some interesting stuff, but it's low-level). I did a lot of Googling yesterday and found some interesting discussion. The following is from [Refactoring Functional Programs by Simon Thompson (2004)](https://kar.kent.ac.uk/14267/1/notes.pdf) (emphasis mine)

> In designing an object-oriented system, it is taken for granted that design will
>   precede programming. Designs will be written using a system like UML
>   which is supported in tools such as Eclipse. Beginning programmers may
>   well learn a visual design approach using systems like BlueJ. Work on a
>   similar methodology for functional programming is reported in [FAD: Functional Analysis and Design](http://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/pubs/2001/1152/), but little
>   other work exists. There may be a number of reasons for this.
>
> - Existing functional programs are of a scale which does not require design.
>     Many functional programs are small, but others, such as the Glasgow Haskell
>     Compiler, are substantial.
> - Functional programs directly model the application domain, thus rendering
>     design irrelevant. **Whilst functional languages provide a variety of powerful
>     abstractions, it is difficult to argue that these provide all and only the
>     abstractions needed to model the real world.**
> - Functional programs are built as an evolving series of prototypes.

In the [PhD thesis cited above](http://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/pubs/2001/1152/), the benefits of using Analysis and design methodologies (ADM) are outlined independent of paradigms. But an argument is made that ADMs should align with the implementation paradigm. That is, OOADM works best for OO programming and is not well applied to another paradigm such as FP. Here's a great quote that I think paraphrases what I call representational gap:

> one can argue at length regarding which paradigm
>   provides the best support for software development, but one achieves the most natural,
>   efficient and effective development package when one remains within a single paradigm
>   from problem description through to implementation and delivery.

Here are the set of diagrams proposed by FAD:

> - function dependency diagrams which present a function with those it uses in its
>     implementation;
> - type dependency diagram which provides the same service for types; 
>     and,
> - module dependency diagrams which present views of the module architecture of the system.

There's a case study in section 5.1 of the FAD thesis, which is a system to automate the production of data relating to a football (soccer) league. The requirements are 100% functional, e.g., input football results, produce league tables, scoring tables, attendance tables, transfer players between teams, updating data after new results, etc. No mention of how FAD works to solve non-functional requirements is documented, apart from stating that "new functionality should be allowed at a minimal cost", something that is nearly impossible to test.

Sadly, apart from FAD, I don't see any modern references for modeling languages (visual) that are proposed for FP. UML is another paradigm, so we should forget that.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20642/discussion-on-question-by-fuhrmanator-does-functional-programming-increase-the).

Answer (score 20):

The basic data is structured the same in pretty much any paradigm. You're going to have a `Student`, a `Course`, etc. whether it's an object, a struct, a record, or whatever.  The difference with OOP isn't how the data is structured, it's how the functions are structured.

I actually find functional programs much more closely match how I think about a problem. For example, to plan a student's schedule for next semester, you think about things like lists of courses a student has completed, courses in a student's degree program, courses offered this semester, courses a student has completed prerequisites for, courses with times that don't conflict, etc.

Suddenly, it's not so clear which class should create and store all these lists. Even less so when you have complex combinations of these lists.  However, you *must* choose one class.

In FP, you write functions that take a student and a list of courses and return a filtered list of courses. You can group all such functions together in a module. You don't have to couple it with one class or another.

So your data models end up looking more like how OOP programmers think of their models, before they get polluted with classes that have no other purpose than providing convenient places to put functions that operate on combinations of other classes. No weird `CourseStudentFilterList` or similar classes that you always end up needing in OOP, but never think about in the beginning design.

Comment: Do you feel the same way about GUI implementations, reporting, immutable data structures or any sort of output in functional languages?

Comment: The question in my mind is why a student's class schedule should serve as a programming archetype.  Suppose instead you want to do simulated annealing to optimize a complex function in several dimensions, and would like the program to finish sometime this year: are either OOP or functional programming a good fit?

Comment: "In FP, you write functions that take a student and a list of courses and return a filtered list of courses." - In OOP that'd probably be a method on a `Student` class. The situation you're talking about, where it really only makes sense for a collection of `T` to hold certain logic rather than the individual `T` does come up, but in my experience it's rarer than you're suggesting, and there usually is a more appropriate class to put the logic on than an otherwise-useless collection class.

Comment: "In OOP, you write methods that take a student and a list of courses and return a filtered list of courses. You can group all such functions together in a class. You don't have to couple it with one class or another." - I took a liberty of replacing concepts. Still cannot see any problems. I think the distinction between OOP and FP is artificial anyway. Why not use both as in C# and Scala?

Comment: @BenAaronson the problem in my experience is that then any function related to a student is added to the Student class and its responsibilities grow and grow until you need to introduce `StudentCourseFilterer` to keep things manageable

Comment: I edited my question to speak about traceability from solution to problem as being a benefit of decreased representational gap. Can you explain in FP how its abstractions are easily traced back to the problem space?

Comment: @BenAaronson I find FP more reusable/composable than OOP. Instead of an ad hoc method on a `Student` class, you have general functions performing general computation whenever you can. Doing some work on a list of Students and returning a filtered result is a typical FP computation that can be applied to almost anything. Why put it in a Student class, unnecessarily constraining yourself? And what if you don't need to give a *name* to the work you're doing on the Student? Why have a method at all?

Comment: @Den Hybrid approaches have their merits. It's not true, however, that the distinction is artificial. There are lots of compromises Scala had to make in order to fit OOP and FP (less powerful type inference is one. Complexity is another: yes, a language that mixes OOP and FP tends to be more *complex* -- as in "hard to use and understand" -- than one of its purer brothers on the two extremes).

Comment: @Den See also Erik Meijer's ["'Mostly Functional' programming doesn't work"](http://queue.acm.org/detail.cfm?ref=rss&id=2611829), which argues against the hybrid approach and for going full "fundamentalist" FP.

Comment: @AndresF. It probably depends on the type of problem, but I rarely encounter a situation where a method like that would be sufficiently reusable. I also think that associating the algorithms with the data make it harder to confuse duplicated code with duplicated knowledge: http://verraes.net/2014/08/dry-is-about-knowledge/ I feel like the mistaken reuse described in that article would be a much easier trap to fall into for FP than OOP, precisely because in OOP you'd have smells like weird class names. As for truly cross-cutting concerns, they tend to be addressable nicely with AOP.

Comment: @AndresF. - I am talking from my practical experience, rather than academic purity. I am comfortable with language allowing shooting myself in the foot if I really want to (which I don't, hence no practical problems).

Comment: @AndresF. Practically though the more language have OOP elements in it the more popular and usable it gets: Haskell < F# < Scala < C#. But it could be a simple matter of better (not "succinct") syntax so not going to insist.

Comment: @BenAaronson That's a very OOP point of view :) With FP, you tend to generalize traversals over stuff, and pass the specific work as a function parameter. In this way, you tend to reduce duplication: there are no multiple ways to do similar things spread over Student, Course, and/or their helpers. AOP seems like a solution to an OOP problem.

Comment: @Den The popularity you describe is, I'm afraid, an accident of history. I use Scala at work, and it's a complex beast due to the way it attempts to mix FP and OOP. Switching to a true FP language like Haskell feels like a breath of fresh air -- and I'm not talking from an academic perspective either!

Comment: @AndresF: FP: int[] func(int) - what does it do filter or sort? vs OOP: IFilter{ ... } ISorter { ... }. Safer DI.

Comment: @Den I can't tell what either of those functions do. However, I can tell you if the first function in FP was a sort or a filter, it would be named [filter](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=filter) or [sort](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=sort), not `func` (just like you named it `IFilter`, etc). In general, in FP you'd name it `func` or `f` when either `sort` or `filter` is a valid choice! For example, when writing a higher-order function that takes `func` as a parameter.

Comment: @AndresF. Right, I guess what I mean is it seems rare that there'd be some list-processing (for example) logic common enough that it should be reused within an application, but application-specific enough that it wouldn't find its way into a general library. Not incredibly rare, but rare enough that it doesn't feel like a major consideration to me, especially when taking into account that just because two functions need to use similar logic now, doesn't necessarily mean they'll vary in the same way in the future.

Comment: @Den Popularity is a function of marketing, and usability is a function with positive feedback (the more used something is, the more used it gets.)

Answer (score 10):

When I took my Java class years ago, we were expected to show our solutions to the entire class, so I got to see how people think; how they solve problems logically.  I fully expected the solutions to cluster around three or four common solutions.  Instead, I watched as 30 students solved the problem in 30 completely different ways.

Naturally, as fledgling programmers gain experience, they will gain exposure to common software patterns, begin using those patterns on their code, and then their solutions may coalesce around a few optimal strategies.  These patterns form a technical language by which experienced developers can communicate.

The technical language that underpins functional programming is *math*.  Accordingly, the problems that are most suitable to solve using functional programming are essentially *math problems.*  By math, I'm not referring to the kind of math that you would see in business solutions, like addition and subtraction.  Rather, I'm talking about the kind of math that you might see on Math Overflow, or the kind of math you would see in Orbitz' search engine (it's written in Lisp).

This orientation has some important ramifications for functional programmers trying to solve real-world programming problems:

1. Functional programming is more declarative than imperative; it concerns itself primarily with telling the computer *what to do, not how to do it.*
2. Object-oriented programs are often built from the top-down.  A class design is created, and the details are filled in.  Functional programs are often built from the bottom-up, starting with small, detailed functions that are combined into higher-level functions.
3. Functional programming can have advantages for prototyping complex logic, constructing flexible programs that can change and evolve organically, and building software where the initial design is unclear.
4. Object-oriented programs can be more suitable for business domains because the classes, messages between objects, and the software patterns all provide a structure that maps to the business domain, captures its business intelligence and documents it.
5. Because all practical software produces side-effects (I/O), purely functional programming languages require a mechanism to produce those side-effects while remaining mathematically pure (monads).
6. Functional programs can be more readily proven, due to their mathematical nature.  Haskell's type system can find things at compile time that most OO languages cannot.

And so on.  As with many things in computing, object-oriented languages and functional languages have different tradeoffs.

Some modern OO languages have adopted some of the useful functional programming concepts, so that you can have the best of both worlds.  Linq, and the language features that were added to support it, is a good example of that.

Comment: What popped up in my mind was something like: functional programming is more about representing a stateless data transformation (map, filter, reduce). OO is much more about using and representing an intrinsic state packed into objects.

Comment: @thepacker: You do have state in functional programming. Only the representation is different: in OOP you use mutable variables whereas in functional programming you can use infinite streams of states that are created on the fly when the program needs to inspect them. Unfortunately, state is often identified with mutable variables, as if mutable variables were the only way to represent state. As a consequence, many believe that a programming language without mutable variables cannot model state.

Comment: @Giorgio: You are absolutely right about having state in fp, this is why i used the word 'more' - it doesn't mean, always. In my time in university I had to implement a lexer, parser and a bytecode compiler via functional programming. It made use of an environment (state) via curring. This was a nice experiment.

Comment: OK - you said it clearly - `the problems that are most suitable to solve using functional programming are essentially math problems.`

Comment: Downvoters... Unless you're simply in a bad mood today, you might consider commenting, given that I haven't stated anything here that's patently untrue.

Comment: @Fuhrmanator: I would rather say that the FP approach to solving problems uses Mathematical concepts. However, you can apply it also to non math problems. For example, I have used Haskell to write programs that (1) analyze log files in a production environment, (2) organizes my files by helping me find duplicates, (3) helps me organize my web browser bookmarks, and so on.

Comment: "Accordingly, the problems that are most suitable to solve using functional programming are essentially math problems.": I do not agree with this statement (see also my previous comment), at least I do not see why it should be true or what it actually means. You can see traversing a directory structure as a math problem and implement it with a recursive function, but since the customer does not see the source code, you are just solving a practical problem like finding a file somewhere in the file system. I find such a distinction between math and non-math problems artificial.

Comment: @Giorgio To me, traversing directory structures or filtering files is a low-level problem (classical computer science which is closer to math than the rest of software engineering), at least within a system that has to provide online ordering and delivery of goods. Of course, OO systems have the same lower-level problems, and I'm not saying they do a better job at solving it. But a class called FileUtilities might make more sense to me what its role is (I'd understand its purpose in the scheme of the solution space and problem space).

Comment: @Fuhrmanator True, in the sense you're talking about, both OOP and FP are low-level. But how does this relate to the "representational gap"?

Comment: @Giorgio: Then help me explain it better.  That FP has a math underpinning is not debatable, and there's more to my answer than that sentence.  The Haskell programs you describe almost certainly use monads, which only exist because of math.  You could do it without monads, but it would almost certainly not be considered "true Haskell" anymore by the purists.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Maybe it is just a matter of terminology. An example of a mathematical problem could be something like: decompose a number into prime factors. A more business-related problem could be: produce a report of all worked hours of an employee and compute her paycheck. You can solve both using pure functional programming (and, if you want, monads). You can then argue that this FP solution uses a lot of mathematical concepts, and I can agree. But even if the **solution** methods use concepts from mathematics, the second problem is not a mathematical problem.

Comment: So, maybe it is only a matter of terminology: I do not consider computing a paycheck or reorganizing bookmarks as mathematical problems, even though I can write FP programs using monads and other abstract concepts (mathematically oriented solutions, if you want) solving them.

Comment: @Giorgio: I'm thinking about math less in terms of addition and subtraction, and more in terms of proofs and higher mathematical abstractions.  I've added some clarifications to my answer.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Ok, so you mean there can be business problems whose solution requires higher mathematical abstractions. I think I understand now. I might have been a bit biased because often mathematical abstractions are considered non-relevant for real-world problems. Thanks for updating your answer.

Comment: @AndresF. perhaps it's all about modularity and organization, but in OO designs it's common to have a domain layer, where objects in the solution map to objects int the problem. Not all of an OO design is low-level details. I'm claiming the representational gap is lower when solution abstractions map to problem abstractions. I think I'm getting the gist that the naturally functional aspects of a problem domain, which relate to data flow, map easily to FP. So again, I'm curious about the problem modeling step in FP that sets up the natural low-gap mapping.

Comment: +1, but I'm not sold on points 2 and 4. I've seen plenty of Haskell tutorials and blog posts that start by tackling a problem top-down, defining all the types and operations to see how it all fits together while leaving every value and function definition undefined (well, defined to throwing an exception). It seems to me that Haskell programmers tend to model the problem *more thoroughly* because they're more inclined to add trivial types for the sake of semantics - e.g. adding a `SafeString` type to represent strings that have been HTML-escaped - and generally keeping more track of effects.

Comment: @Doval That's how a Haskeler friend told me to start working on a Haskell function: sprinkling "undefined"s wherever I don't have an implementation yet :) It seems top-down to me.

Comment: @doval: I'm more used to less strongly-typed functional languages like Lisp and Scheme, instead of Haskell.  Regardless, while one can design from the bottom up in OO languages, it's not common, and when it's done, the resulting code has a more "functional" feel to it.  I daresay this is probably how the TDD'ers approach design.

Comment: "the problems that are most suitable to solve using functional programming are essentially math problems."  That simply is not true.  The fact that the concept of Monads comes from category theory also does not mean that mathematical tasks are the most natural/fit domain for functional languages.  All it means is that code written in strongly typed functional languages can be described, analysed and reasoned about using mathematics.  This is a powerful extra feature, not something which stops you writing "Barbie Horse Adventures" in Haskell.

Comment: @itsbruce: I'm more than happy to use a different metaphor if you can tell me what that is.  But anyone who's ever tried standing up a website with a functional language knows quite clearly that the process looks and feels very different from OO.

Comment: @itsbruce Barbie Horse Adventures is a serious mathematical simulation of the highest caliber, it's pidgeon holing FP into overly-complex numerical projections like matrices describing the physical shimmering of Barbie's hair over a discrete period in a variety of possible real world environments that convinces people to completely dismiss it as irrelevant to their every-day business problem coding.

Comment: Your analogy with 30 students is interesting, but I doubt that your "Java class" taught you an analysis/design/methodology (ADM), eg. CRC cards, or that it was followed by all 30 students. My first OO class in Ada (1984) used the Booch method and our solutions all had the same high-level design. Classes were the nouns in the problem statement given to us by the instructor. Decreasing representational gap requires following a good ADM. One of the edits I made cites a paper from 2004 that says FP potentially lacks abstractions suited to real-world, supporting #4.

Comment: @Fuhrmanator: Of course.  But the opposite is also true; many programmers get so devoted to software patterns and design methodologies that they effectively stop thinking.  Slavish adherence to doctrine stifles creativity and stops innovation.

Answer (score 6):

I would like to stress an aspect that I find important and that has not been covered in the other answers.

First of all, I think that the representational gap between problems and solutions can be more in the mind of the programmer, according to their background and to the concepts they are more familiar with.

OOP and FP look at data and operations from two different perspectives and provide different tradeoffs, as Robert Harvey has pointed out already.

One important aspect in which they differ is the way in which they allow to extend your software.

Consider the situation in which you have a collection of data types and a collection of operations, for example you have different image formats and you maintain a library of algorithms to process images.

Functional programming makes it easier to add new operations to your software: you only need a local change in your code, namely you add a new function, which handles different input data formats. On the other hand, adding new formats is more involved: you need to change all the functions you have already implemented (non local change).

The object-oriented approach is symmetric to this: each data type carries its own implementation of all the operations and is responsible of choosing the right implementation at runtime (dynamic dispatching). This makes it easy to add a new data type (e.g. a new image format): you just add a new class and implement all its methods. On the other hand, adding a new operation means to change all the classes that need to provide that operation. In many languages this is done by extending an interface and adapting all classes implementing it.

This different approach to extension is one of the reasons why OOP is more appropriate for certain problems where the set of operations varies less often than the set of data types on which these operations work. A typical example are GUIs: you have a fixed set of operations that all widgets must implement (`paint`, `resize`, `move`, and so on) and a collection of widgets that you want to extend.

So, according to this dimension, OOP and FP are just two specular ways of organizing your code. See [SICP](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-17.html), in particular Section 2.4.3, Table 2.22, and paragraph **Message passing**.

Summarizing: in OOP you use data to organize operations, in FP you use operations to organize data. Each approach is stronger or weaker according to the context. In general, none of the two has a higher representational gap between problem and solution.

Comment: Actually, Visitor Pattern (in OOP) gives you same power as you said for FP. It allows you to add new operations while making adding new classes harder. I wonder if you can do same in FP (eg. adding new formats instead of operations).

Comment: The image processing scenario doesn't seem like the best example. Surely you'd convert the images into some internal format and process that instead of writing separate implementations of all your image processing stuff for each image type?

Comment: @Hey: Your entry point function still needs to pick the right converter function according to its input. The point is how you organize your dispatch: in FP each function has the responsibility of dispatching according to its input, in OOP each object (piece of data) contains the information that is used to find the correct implementation of an operation.

Comment: @Giorgio maybe I'm not getting the intended meaning from this part: "adding new formats is more involved: you need to change all the functions you have already implemented."

Comment: @Hey Giorgio is likely referring to the so-called [Expression Problem](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ExpressionProblem). "Adding new formats" means "adding new constructors (aka 'cases') to a datatype".

Comment: @Hey: Have you read the chapter of SICP I have suggested. There is worked out example there. Anyway, suppose you have a function that scales an image (changes the resolution). This function will start by identifying the format of the image and then dispatch to the proper implementation for that image format. If you add a new image format, you have to change the code that identifies the image format to handle the new format. You have to do this for every other function working on images: non local change.

Comment: @Euphoric: I have not looked into the details, but the FP counterpart to the visitor pattern should involve an `Other` variant / constructor in your data type, and an extra function parameter to be passed to all functions to handle the _other_ case. It is, of course, awkward / less natural with respect to the OOP solution (dynamic dispatch). In the same way, the visitor pattern is awkward / less natural than the FP solution (a higher-order function).

Comment: In my opinion this answer kind of misses the point since neither paradigm places restrictions on which axis of the expression problem you want to align yourself with. In OOP you have `interfaces` when you want fixed operations and an open set of cases, and visitors when you want the converse. In an FP language you'd use a record of functions or an algebraic data type, respectively. It's not even a matter of preference or one being better than the other; the "correct" choice depends on the problem you're solving. The most useful view of FP is that it emphasizes *values* instead of side effects.

Comment: @Doval: Regarding the expression problem, each paradigm makes it easier to extend you code in a certain way, and needs to use a more complex solution otherwise, or am I missing something? This is why (as you say) the choice for one of the two views depends on the problem you are solving, e.g. programming a GUI (OOP) or an interpreter for a programming language (FP). Regarding values versus side-effects: I would say side-effects characterize the imperative approach, i.e. not only OOP, but also the procedural paradigm.

Comment: @Giorgio I'm not sure what the "more complex solution" you refer to is. An OOP language could have pattern matching if it wanted to (see: Scala); it's an orthogonal problem. If it doesn't, implementing visitor isn't difficult, just verbose. Creating an interface isn't difficult in an FP language; they generally have first-class functions with lexical scope and records.

Answer (score 5):

Most functional languages are not Object-Oriented.  That does not mean they have no objects (in the sense of complex types which have specific functionality associated with them).  Haskell, like java, has Lists, Maps, Arrays, all kinds of Trees and many other complex types.  If you look at the Haskell List or Map module you will see a set of functions very similar to the methods in most equivalent OO-language library modules.  If you inspect the code, you will even find similar encapsulation, with some types (or their constructors, to be precise) and functions only usable by other functions in the module.

The way you work with these types in Haskell is often hardly different from the OO way.  In Haskell I say

```
  null xs
  length xs
```

and in Java you say

```
  xs.isEmpty
  xs.length
```

Tomato, tomato.  The Haskell functions are not tied to the object but they are closely associated with its type. ¨Ah, *but*,¨ you say, ¨in Java it is calling which ever **length** method is appropriate to the actual class of that object¨.  Surprise - Haskell does [polymorphism](https://wiki.haskell.org/Polymorphism) too with [type classes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_class) (and other things).

In Haskell, if I have **is** - a collection of integers - it does not matter whether the collection is a list or set or array, this code

```
  fmap (* 2) is
```

will return a collection with all the elements doubled.  Polymorphism means that the appropriate **map** function for the specific type will be called.

These examples are, in truth, not really complex types but the same applies in more difficult problems.  The idea that functional languages do not let you model complex objects and associate specific functionality with them is simply wrong.

There *are* important and significant differences between the functional and OO style but I don´t think this answer has to deal with them.  You asked if functional languages prevent (or hinder) intuitive modelling of problems and tasks.  The answer is No.

Comment: As a matter of fact, you can use type classes in Java/C#; you just to explicitly pass the dictionary of functions, instead of having the compiler infer the correct one based on the type.

Comment: Oh, definitely.  As William Cook said, much OO code actually makes more frequent use of higher order functions than functional code does, even though the coder probably is not aware of it.

Comment: I like your answer because it has concrete examples, but the abstractions are data structures, which have been around since C. What about writing software for a business domain, such as microbiology or a judicial system? How does a FP solution look when you need to model business entities in the solution, e.g., proteins and molecules, or trials and defendants?

Comment: You are making a false distinction.  A list is no more an inert data structure than a stack or a queue or a tic-tac-toe simulator.  A list can hold anything (in Haskell it might well be partially applied functions) and defines how those things can be interacted with.  You could apply a list full of partially applied functions to another list of values and the result would be a new list containing every possible combination of functions from the first and input from the second.  That's much more than a C struct.

Comment: Types are used for more varied things in functional languages than imperative/OO ones (the type systems tend to be more powerful and consistent, for one thing).  Types and their functions are used to shape code paths (which is why several functional languages simply do not have keywords for loops - not needed), for example.

Comment: @itsbruce I realize FP is much more than C. The question is about how is it easy to understand the solution that shows the relationship between a Protein and a Molecule. I can do a class diagram in UML showing that relationship (the problem domain), and my OO solution can therefore mimic it in a lot of ways. There's traceability from the problem to the solution. I'm not seeing how this is done in FP at a higher level (before functions).

Comment: @Fuhrmanator "I'm not seeing how this is done in FP" So you're complaining something you don't understand doesn't make sense; go learn it, understand it thoroughly, and then it will make sense. Maybe after it makes sense you'll decide it is crap and you don't need others to prove it to you, though other people such as above do understand it and haven't come to that conclusion. You appear to have brought a knife to a gun fight, and now you're telling everybody that guns are useless because they aren't sharp.

Comment: @Jimmy Hoffa I don't think that's entirely fair.  There are a ton of FP examples out there for relatively simple collection and math operations, and not many for other types of problems.  And when people ask how to do the complex stuff, the answer is often "See how easy and elegant this fairly simple list operation is?  Just do it like that, but for [problem here] instead" which leaves a lot to be desired.  I understand that complex programs tend to be overly large to fit into an answer, but "The details are left as an exercise for the reader" isn't helpful by itself.

Answer (score 4):

FP does indeed strive for a reduction in the representational gap:

Something you'll see a lot of in functional languages is the practice of building the language up (using bottom-up design) into an [Embedded Domain Specific Language (EDSL)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language). This lets you develop a means of expressing your business concerns in a way that is natural for your domain within the programming language. Haskell and Lisp both pride themselves on this.

Part (if not all) of what enables this ability is more flexibility and expressiveness within the base language(s) itself; with first class functions, higher-order functions, function composition, and in some languages, [algebraic data types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_data_type) (AKA discriminated unions) and the ability to define operators*, there's more flexibility available for how to express things than there is with OOP, which means you'll probably find more natural ways to express things from your problem domain. (It should say something that many OOP languages have been adopting many of these features recently, if not starting out with them.)

<sub>* Yes, in many OOP languages you can override the standard operators, but in Haskell, you can define new ones!</sub>

In my experience working with functional languages (mostly F# and Haskell, some Clojure, and a little Lisp and Erlang), I have an easier time mapping the problem space down into the language than I do with OOP -- especially with algebraic data types, which I find more flexible than classes. Something that threw me for a loop when starting out with FP, particularly with Haskell, was that I had to think/work at a bit higher level than I was used to in imperative or OOP languages; you might be running into this a bit as well.

Comment: Business concerns (from the customer) aren't expressed very often in higher-order functions. But a customer can write a one-line user story and provide you with business rules (or you can get them out of the customer). I'm interested in the (top-down?) domain modeling (from those artefacts) that allows us to arrive at abstractions of the problem that map to first-class functions, etc. Can you cite some references? Can you use a concrete example of a domain, the abstractions, etc.?

Comment: @Fuhrmanator A customer can still write one-line user stories and business rules *regardless of whether you use OOP and FP*. I don't expect customers to understand higher-order functions any more than I expect them to understand inheritance, composition or interfaces.

Comment: @Fuhrmanator How often have you had the customer express their concerns in terms of Java generics or abstract base classes and interfaces?  Dear God.  Paul has given you a very good answer, explaining a practical and reliable method of modelling using techniques which are surely not too hard to visualise.  And yet you insist that it be described in terms of one specific modelling technique for one particular paradigm, as if that were somehow the most natural way to represent design and anything else can be redrawn in its terms.

Comment: @Fuhrmanator This might not be as high-level as you're looking for but should give some insight into the design process using functional techniques: [Designing With Types](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/series/designing-with-types.html). I'd recommend browsing that site in general because it has some excellent articles.

Comment: @Fuhrmanator There's also this [Thinking Functionally](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/series/thinking-functionally.html) series

Comment: @itsbruce `Paul has given you a very good answer....` Thank you for your kind words, kind sir -- at least I'm guessing you're a sir based on your username (would that make it a sirname[sic]?)

Comment: @paul Thanks for those refs, very constructive feedback.

Answer (score 3):

As Niklaus Wirth put it, "Algorithms + Data Structures = Programs". Functional programming is about the way to organize algorithms, and it does not tell a lot about ways to organize data structures. Indeed, there exist FP languages both with mutable (Lisp) and immutable (Haskell, Erlang) variables. If you want to compare and contrast FP with something, you should pick imperative (C, Java) and declarative (Prolog) programming.

OOP is on the other hand a way to build data structures and attach algorithms to them. FP does not prevent you from building data structures similar to OOP ones. If you don't believe me, have a look at Haskell type declarations. However, most FP languages agree that functions do not belong to data structures and should rather be in the same namespace. This is done in order to simplify building new algorithms via function composition. Indeed, if you know what input a function takes and what output it produces, why should it matter which data structure it belongs too? For example, why does `add` function have to be called on an instance of Integer type and passed an argument instead of simply being passed two Integer arguments?

Therefore, I don't see why FP should make solutions harder to understand in general, and I don't think it does it anyway. However, keep in mind that a seasoned imperative programmer will certainly find functional programs harder to understand than imperative ones, and vice versa. This is similar to Windows - Linux dichotomy when folks who have invested 10 years in becoming comfortable with Windows environment find Linux difficult after a month of usage, and those who are used to Linux cannot achieve the same productivity in Windows. Hence, the 'representational gap' you are talking about is very subjective.

Comment: Because of encapsulation and data hiding, which are not OO principles per se, I don't entirely agree with OO being data structures + algorithms (that's the internal view only). The beauty of any good abstraction is that there's some service it provides to solve part of the problem, without one needing to understand too many of the details. I think you're talking encapsulation when you separate functions and data in FP, but I'm too green to know for sure. Also, I edited my question to refer to tracing from the solution back to the problem (to clarify the meaning of representational gap).

Comment: `if you know what input a function takes and what output it produces, why should it matter which data structure it belongs too?` That sounds a lot like cohesion, which for any modular system is important. I'd argue that not knowing where to find a function would make it harder to understand a solution, which is due to higher representational gap. Lots of OO systems have this problem, but it's because of bad design (low cohesion). Again, the namespace issue is out of my expertise in FP, so maybe it's not as bad as it sounds.

Comment: @Fuhrmanator But you *do* know where to find a function. And there is only one function, not multiple functions with the same name, defined for each datatype (again, see the "Expression Problem"). For example, for Haskell library functions (which you're encouraged to use, instead of rediscovering the wheel or making a slightly less useful versions of said functions), you have wonderful discovery tools such as [Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle), which is so powerful it lets you [search by signature](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=Ord+a+%3D%3E+%5Ba%5D+-%3E+%5Ba%5D) (try it! :) )

Comment: @Fuhrmanator, after "That sounds a lot like cohesion", I would have expected you to logically conclude that FP languages let you write programs with higher cohesion but you surprized me. :-) I think you should pick an FP language, learn it and decide for your own. If I were you, I'd suggest to start with Haskell since it is quite pure and therefore will not let you write code in imperative style. Erlang and some Lisp are also good choices but they mix in other programming styles. Scala and Clojure, IMO, are quite complicated to start from.